# How to import one of JScience's classes?

Tags: java, jscience

I am trying to use one of JScience's classes. I downloaded it from the [website](https://java.net/projects/jscience/downloads) and I got a zip file. I unzipped the file and got a jar file and some folders. What I am supposed to do now to import the [class](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/SparseVector.html) that I need?

Comment: Put the JAR somewhere on your CLASSPATH and import the package that contains your class.

Comment: @PM 77-1 So the default CLASSPATH is ".", then I would put the JAR there and call `import org.jscience.mathematics.vector;` ?

Comment: `import org.jscience.mathematics.vector.*;`

Comment: Are you using any IDE (Eclipse or others)?

Comment: I am using Sublime Text.

Comment: Not familiar, so I do not know whether it manages its own build path.